# Test nodejs methode with Mocha and chai libraries

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I want to test this methode below with Mocha and chai, but I got an error :
I want to test this methode below with Mocha and chai, but I got an error :

```
exports.getCaracteristiques = (req,res) => {
  db.query('SELECT "titi", "toto"')
.then( ({rows}) => {
  var caracteristiqueResult = rows.map((row) => {
    return {
      'idCaracteristique': row.CARACT_ID
      , 'libelleCaracteristique': row.toto
      , 'libelleCaracteristique': row.titi

    };
  })
  res.json(caracteristiqueResult);
})
.catch(err => {
  // handle the error
  console.log("ERROR :", err)
  res.status(500).end(err)
})
   };
```

test.js file contains :

```
var expect = require('chai').expect; 
require("../config/config");


var ctr = require('../api/controllers/caracteristiques')

describe('Caracteristiques', () => {

it('returns an array of Carateristiques', () => {
    // This will fail if "Caracteristiques result "is
    // not  array.

    return ctr.getCaracteristiques.then(function(data){
        expect(data).to.be.a('array');

    });// no catch, it'll figure it out since the promise is rejected

  });
   })
```

but I got this error :

```
 Caracteristiques
1) returns an array of Carateristiques


 0 passing (0ms)
 1 failing

 1) Caracteristiques
   returns an array of Carateristiques:
     TypeError: ctr.getCaracteristiques.then is not a function
    at Context.it (test\caracteristiques.js:13:40)
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

```
TypeError: ctr.getCaracteristiques.then is not a function
```

Is just plain right. You missed the `()` when onvoking the `getCaracteristiques()` method.

This should work:

```
return ctr.getCaracteristiques().then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.be.a('array');
});
```

Edit after OP comment:

In your code, `getCaracteristiques` requires a `req` and a `res` objects. My guess is that your using [express](https://expressjs.com/) or any other node js http library, which usually fills that for you.

In mocha, we are calling the method by ourselves, without any web server, so we need to craft those objects by ourselves.

The `getCaracteristiques` method does not use `req`, but it does needs `res`to have a `json()` method. So we can do:

```
const res = {
  json: (a) => a,
};

return ctr.getCaracteristiques({}, res).then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.be.a('array');
});
```

In our test so `getCaracteristiques` return what we want (just the data, because the fake `json`method just yields away its parameter).

Now, the test will fail again, because `getCaracteristiques` does not return the `json`call. If we add a `return` statement, the whole thing should work:

```
exports.getCaracteristiques = (req,res) => {
  return db.query('SELECT "CARACT_ID", "CARACT_LIB", "COULEUR", "IMAGE_ACTIVE", 
  "IMAGE_PASSIVE", "ACTIF" FROM "DIM_PRC_CARACT"')
  .then( ({rows}) => {
  var caracteristiqueResult = rows.map((row) => {
    return {
      'idCaracteristique': row.CARACT_ID
      , 'libelleCaracteristique': row.CARACT_CD
      , 'libelleCaracteristique': row.CARACT_LIB
      , 'couleurCaracteristique': row.COULEUR
      , 'pictogrammeActifCaracteristique': row.IMAGE_PASSIVE
      , 'pictogrammePassifCaracteristique': row.IMAGE_PASSIVE
    };
  })
  return res.json(caracteristiqueResult);
})
```

Note that a `return` was added to `db.query` and `res.json`, so the `getCaracteristiques` method now returns a promise of the caracteristiques.

Comment: Thanks you are right but obviously, I got another error :ERROR : TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
    at db.query.then (C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\api\controllers\caracteristiques.js:18:11)

Comment: can you help please because this the first time I do Unit Test with Mocha

Comment: when I put this line res.json(caracteristiqueResult); in comment I got another error : Caracteristiques
       returns an array of Carateristiques:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
      at Context.it (test\caracteristiques.js:13:41)

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps

Comment: thnak you very much that works as expected! I have a question, Why we use two returns ?